# Navigate SDK in Android - Is there a method to also make navigate maneuver arrow disapear when I setRouteVisible to false in VisualNavigator?

Tags: here-api, navigator

I wanted to make route keep from the screen, so I called setRouteVisible to false in VisualNavigator.
But I found that there still was the maneuver arrow show up on the screen, like the picture.
[image: maneuver arrow still show up picture]

I tried to use visualNavigatorColors.maneuverArrowColor = Color.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT).
But the arrow became black.
How can I make maneuver arrow disapear when navigating?

Answer (score 0):

`VisualNavigatorColors` has a member `maneuverArrowColor`. You can set a clear color, ie. with full transparency and the arrow will not be rendered.

Note that color is of type `com.here.sdk.core.Color`. So, setting it like this should work:

```
visualNavigatorColors.maneuverArrowColor = Color.valueOf(0, 1f, 1f, 1f); //ARGB
```